# axios-mock-adapter not matching url as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I used to use axios-mock-adapter with great success, but the last few times i've tried to use it, my routes never seem to match and it is still trying to execute a real endpoint.

Why is this unit test still making a call to example.com and returning a 404? I would have expected it to return a 500.

test/libs/orgService/index.spec.js

```
const uuid = require('uuidv4')
const axios = require('axios')
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter')
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
const { getOrgById } = require('../../../src/libs/orgService/index')
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised)
const expect = chai.expect
const orgServiceHost = 'https://example.com'

describe.only('#getOrgById failure', () => {
  const id = uuid()
  before(() => {
    console.log('`${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}` = ', `${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}`)
    mock.onGet(`${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}`).reply(500) <-- SHOULD BE RETURNING 500!!
  })

  after(() => {
    mock.reset()
  })

  it('should fail to fetch an organization', () => {
    return expect(getOrgById(orgServiceHost, id, tkn)).to.eventually.be.rejected
  })
})
```

src/libs/orgService/index.js

```
const axios = require('axios')

function getOrgById (orgServiceHost, id, token) {
  log.debug('orgServiceHost = ', orgServiceHost)
  log.debug('id = ', id)
  log.debug('token = ', token)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (id === undefined) {
      return resolve()
    }
    console.log('`${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}` = ', `${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}`)
    axios({
      url: `${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        return resolve(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        log.error('getOrgById err = ', err)
        return reject(err)
      })
  })
}

module.exports = { getOrgById }
```

Comment: last time I used axios (-mock-adapter) I only provided [url-paths](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig) with `url:` but the host via `baseURL:`, can you check by removing the schema and host and only operate on the path `(/a/b/c/{id})` ?

Comment: alternatively there's this [bug#136](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/issues/136) which breaks `onGet` if the uri has no trailing `/`

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I don't have enough credit to comment so posting the below as answer.)

I'm not sure if this will work but please try creating an axios instance

```
before(() => {
 instance = AxiosApi.getAxiosInstance();
 mock = new MockAdapter(instance);
 mock.onGet(`${orgServiceHost}/organizations/${id}`).reply(500);
})
```

Comment: what is `AxiosApi`?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you return a `Promise` from the service. Try something like:

```
it('should fail to fetch an organization', (done) => {
    getOrgById(orgServiceHost, id, tkn)
      .then(() => {
        assert.fail("custom error message"); // or any other failure here
        done();
      }).catch((exception) => {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy(); // or any other way to pass the test
        done();
      });
  });
```